# \listoftheorems not appearing on pdfbookmark

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I'm using thmtools \listoftheorems to generate a list of the theorems that I use in my thesis. So far so good, I've been able to put the list in my table of contents. However, there is no entry for the generated list on the pdf bookmarks, see the image bellow. Can you guys help me or point me to a location where I can fix this issue?

[image: not adding to the bookmarks]

Minimal Sample:

```
% DOC CLASS
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

% METADATA
\author{Marcos}
\title{TeX StackExchange Minimal Doc}

% THEOREM DEF
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M,name=Definition]{definition}

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \pdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{contents}   
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftheorems\clearpage

    \section{First Section}
    \begin{definition}[TeX StackExchange]
        TeX StackExchange is a nice place! =)
    \end{definition}
    \lipsum

        \subsection{First Subsection}
        \begin{definition}[StackExchange]
            StackExchange is a great platform too!
        \end{definition}
        \lipsum

    \section{Second Section}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,
Marcos

Comment: It's quite difficult to guess at how you did the insertion of the list of definitions in the table of contents. Please, add a minimal example of your code.

Comment: Hi @egreg, I just added the minimal example. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Add `\clearpage\pdfbookmark{List of Theorems}{theorems}` before `\listoftheorems`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the list of theorems should also go in to the table of contents, then `\addcontentsline` can be used that automatically adds an entry for the bookmarks. Otherwise `\pdfbookmark` can be used for an entry to the bookmarks only. `\cleardoublepage` ensures the right page for the anchor setting by `\pdfbookmark` or `\phantomsection`, the latter provides the anchor for `\addcontensline`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  openlevel=1,
  numbered
}

% METADATA
\author{Marcos}
\title{TeX StackExchange Minimal Doc}

% THEOREM DEF
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M,name=Definition]{definition}

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}% removes warning about duplicate destination `page.1'
    \maketitle
    \cleardoublepage
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
    \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    % \pdfbookmark{\listtheoremname}{theorems}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtheoremname}
    \listoftheorems\clearpage

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{First Section}
    \begin{definition}[TeX StackExchange]
        TeX StackExchange is a nice place! =)
    \end{definition}
    \lipsum

        \subsection{First Subsection}
        \begin{definition}[StackExchange]
            StackExchange is a great platform too!
        \end{definition}
        \lipsum

    \section{Second Section}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```